# Everytime I run a VBA Macro, it disables my NUM LOCK

Tags: excel, vba

At first, I thought it was an issue with Windows 10, however, after trying several solutions I gave up until I coincidentally realized that running a VBA macro was disabling **and** enabling my NUM-KEY.

```
Sub NewLineInventory()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim isProtected As Boolean

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")

' Checks if the worksheet is protected
isProtected = ws.ProtectContents

    ' Use error handling to ensure the worksheet is protected again
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Code to make edits in the worksheet
    Range("A4").EntireRow.Insert

    Range("A5:W5").Copy
    Range("A4").PasteSpecial
    Range("E4").ClearContents
    Range("R4").ClearContents
    Range("T4").ClearContents
    Range("A4") = "No"

    SendKeys ("{ESC}")

    ' Reset error handling
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

I tried removing any code line related to protection and it the issue disappears.
Does anyone have any idea why?

FYI. The protection code lines are added to allow VBA to make edits to the worksheet without requiring a password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the copy paste activity with the ESC key-send? Use `Application.CutCopyMode = False` instead.

Comment: It's the `Sendkeys`. Why do you need to use it?

Comment: It is recommended to always specify the workbook and worksheet when using Range. Here you are using the default active worksheet, which might be or not the same as ws.
using ws.Range(...) instead of Range only will avoid any misinterpretations.

Comment: @Rory You are right, it was the sendkeys. I used it to remove the copy lines around the cell, but people here already fixed that for me. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug.

`Sendkeys "{ESC}"` actually hits **ESCAPE** and **NUMLOCK**, it would seem.

You can put `Sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}"` on the next line after the `Sendkeys "{ESC}"` to revert it.

However, if you're just using **ESCAPE** to clear the after-paste visual, you don't need the Sendkeys at all, you can just use:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: You not only identify my problem but also helped me fix it with a workaround. Thanks!